# What if a black hole of normal matter and a black hole of antimatter collided?

Tags: black-holes, big-bang, antimatter

This is a curiosity question. Considering same mass black holes. As nothing can come out of either black hole, would the annihilation result into a black hole of energy? Assuming the two black holes do not repel one another - i.e. assuming antimatter does not have opposite gravity.

Could the big bang have been one such collision between black holes of unequal masses where black hole of normal matter was heavier?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38374/discussion-on-question-by-kpv-what-if-a-black-hole-of-normal-matter-and-a-black).